# Can't overload "." operator in swift

Tags: swift

Even though the swift documentation says that we can overload the . symbol I can't seem to do so without the compiler complaining.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
operator infix . {}

@infix func . (left:Vector2D, right:Vector2D) -> Vector2D {
  //func
}
```

Has anyone successfully done this in swift?

Comment: i read that differently you can build your own operator using the following set of symbols `/ = - + * % < > ! & | ^ . ~` thus you could define `<->` or `.....`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `.` character [*in* a custom operator](http://terribleswiftideas.tumblr.com/post/87998245379/to-go-along-with-the-and-the-operators-the), but you can't create an operator that's the `.` character alone — it looks like that token is a more basic part of the grammar. (Actually, it looks like there are more restrictions on `.` than you see in the grammar part of the [language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-XID_794), because you can create the extended-silence operator `......`, but not the happy operator `^.^`.)

(Think about it this way: if you tried to use `.` to define the dot product of two vectors, you'd have a hard time using it to address members of those vectors.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might misunderstand the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_28).

> It is not possible to overload the default assignment operator (=). Only the **compound assignment operators** can be overloaded. Similarly, the ternary conditional operator (a ? b : c) cannot be overloaded.

`.` is obviously not a [compound assignment operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_assignment), it's a member selection operator.

However, you can

> declare and implement your own custom operators **in addition to** the standard operators provided by Swift. Custom operators can be defined only with the characters / = - + * % < > ! & | ^ . ~.

Comment: mathematical operators (+, -, etc), prefix operators, postfix operators, etc are all not compound assignment operators. you are looking at the wrong part of the documentation. see the last section of the documentation you linked

Comment: @pseudonym117 The question was asking if `.` can be overloaded which is not allowed but it can be used as a part of custom operators. That's what my answer was trying to say.